# $('id or class name').click(function() vs $(document).on('click', '.id or classname', function(e)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the difference between `$('id or class name').click(function() vs $(document).on('click', '.id or classname', function(e)`.

1. How to best use each one.
2. What is the situation that use each one.
3. What is the advantage of one over the other

I have a couple of examples where `$(document).on('click', '.id or class-name', function()` works and `$('id or class name').click(function()` did not work the most recent encounter is one during this project of mine where I generate a table with values then at the last TD i have an anchor with a class named `add`. I made it a class so event if I have multiple generated row the click event will still fire but again using `$('#add').click` didn't work while using `$(document).on('click', '.id or class-name', function(e)` worked.

Also this is not same but using `$('#file')` didn't work here so i just added it.

Getting the content of input file using id 
`var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];` worked but `var file = $('#file').files[0];`

T check the file like this

```
var name = file.name;
var size = file.size;
var type = file.type;
console.log("name " + name);
console.log("size " + size);
console.log("type " + type);
```

The result of this is

```
name whomovedmycheese - Copy.pdf
size 500624
type application/pdf
```

I know that using `$('# or . then name')` will select the id or class but why is it not working during these times. Some may just point me to document I read them but I don't think i fully understand all of them that is why I am confused on these thing. Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Only typo error sir Manoz i wanted to fix it but someone already did it for me

Comment: ` $('#file')` is a jQuery element. ` $('#file')[0]` is the raw DOM element. To access files you need the files property of the raw DOM element ` $('#file')[0].files[0]` would work.

Comment: @Moogs let me try it and i will be back on you on this

Comment: i see it did work so using $('# or . ') alone does not use or access DOM? Is this what your trying to say?

Comment: @HogRider: No, he is not. He is saying that a jQuery object is not a DOM element.  A jQuery object is a **wrapper** around a collection ofDOM elements. If you want to access a property of the DOM element (e.g. `files`), then you need to either access the underlying DOM elements (`$('#file')[0]`) or use `.prop`: `$('$file').prop('files')`.

Comment: Yeah Felix is right, I should of said jQuery object instead of jQuery element.

Comment: from the link i think i understand it a bit my follow up question is this for example i have this many element i put on single event handles for them do i need to change it so all of them can listen to parent event?Does this improve the performance of the project?

Comment: @HogRider it improves the performance because you have less click handlers which means there is less memory being allocated